# Ubuntu 12.10 cURL with proxy

Tags: 12.04, curl

I´m using proxy and don´t have problems with anything except cURL.

Anytime i try to do:

```
curl -L http://link.to.something
```

i receive:

```
curl: (5) Couldn't resolve proxy 'http'
```

Nevertheless:

```
curl --proxy http://myproxy.com:8080 -L http://link.to.something
```

will work good.

Is there any solution for not writing `--proxy` everytime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From man curl:

```
-x, --proxy <[protocol://][user@password]proxyhost[:port]>

 Use the specified HTTP proxy. 
 If the port number is not specified, it is assumed at port 1080.
```

For general use, declare environment variables for http/https

```
export http_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:port/
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
```

1. edit /etc/bash.bashrc add to the end of file :

> ```
>     export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.com:port/
>     export https_proxy=$http_proxy
>     export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.com:port/
> ```

- OR proxy no username and password case - :

> ```
>     export http_proxy=http://proxyserver.com:port/
>     export https_proxy=$http_proxy
>     export ftp_proxy=http://proxyserver.com:port/
> ```

Comment: seems like i lacked `export https_proxy=$http_proxy` line in my `~/.bashrc`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that you have a http_proxy environment variable set. By default curl tries to use that first. Your http_proxy is also apparently invalid. To see what you have there, type:

```
echo $http_proxy
```

You'd need to check where you're setting http_proxy and fixing that so that it points to the correct one.

The other answer is much more complete than mine :)